# Google Programmable Search Engine changes url to /

Tags: search

I'm using Google Programmable Search Engine on my site and the actual url is something like /search.  That page has the Google code embedded into it.  When that page is accessed with the querystring params for the search, Google's javascript changes the URL to / with the search parameters appended.

If anyone tries to share that URL, they get the home page, not the search page.  Any ideas on how to prevent Google from changing the URL path?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution? Example: this domainname.tld/google-search becomes this domainname.tld/#gsc.tab=0 (i.e the home page and not the /google-search page).

Comment: Update. Ok. I found out that since the page created is on vBulletin 5, the vB5 javascripts are the cause of the conflict.